# Integration in R: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" Error

Tags: r, bayesian, numerical-integration

I am trying to use R to calculate the marginal likelihood of a set of data (`likelihood_N`) with respect to the parameter $v_0$. To do this, I created the following subfunctions:

```
prior_u= function(v0, v){
    1/40}

likelihood=function(v0,data){
#turns dataframe to vectors
    Gmu=data[2]$V2
    v=data[1]$V1
    
    G=(1 - (1/g)*(sqrt(log(2)/pi)) * exp(- (log(2)*((v-v0)^2))/(g^2)))
    return(dnorm(Gmu,G,s))
}

likelihood_N=function(v0,data){
    prod(likelihood(v0,data))*prior_u(v0,data[1]$V1)
}
```

However when I use the`integrate` R built in function it always gives me the following error message:

> Warning message in (v - v0):
> "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
>
> Error in integrate(likelihood_N, start, stop, dataset_1, subdivisions = N): evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

Regardless of the number of subdivisions I choose. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I'm really new to R so I don't know if there are any other integration functions I could use instead to calculate the marginal likelihood. I tried to create my own algorithm of histogram-based integration, but it's very ineffective and I'd like to compare the results I'm getting to be sure they are correct, since they seem lower than I anticipated.

Answer (score 3):

The `integrate` function supplies a vector with multiple `v0` values to your `likelihood_N`, but your function is written to handle only a single number `v0`.